# C++ - read and write pcapng files without libpcap

Tags: pcap-ng

I'm interested in reading and writing pcapng files without using libpcap or WinPcap. Anyone knows how to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can recommend a C-library which does that, it's called [LightPcapNg](https://github.com/rvelea/LightPcapNg) and apparently [PcapPlusPlus](https://github.com/seladb/PcapPlusPlus/blob/master/Pcap%2B%2B/header/PcapFileDevice.h) is using it to have a cleaner C++ wrapper.

Since you're interested in C++, here is a code snippet of how to read a pcap-ng file using PcapPlusPlus:

```
#include <PcapFileDevice.h>

void readAndWritePcapNg(char* inputFileName, char* outputFileName)
{
    // reader instance
    PcapNgFileReaderDevice readerDev(inputFileName);

    // writer instance
    PcapNgFileWriterDevice writerDev(outputFileName);

    // open reader and writer
    readerDev.open();
    writerDev.open();

    RawPacket rawPacket;

    // read packets from file
    while (readerDev.getNextPacket(rawPacket))
    {
        Packet packet(&rawPacket);

        // do whatever you want with the packet
        ....
        ....

        // write the packet to the output file
        writerDev.writePacket(rawPacket);
    }

    // close reader and writer
    readerDev.close();
    writerDev.close();
}
```

Comment: How can I do that with Libpcap?